# JWT admin, user etc

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I have a system where SPA(React) and I use JWT auth(Node JS). How should I get the role on the Client side(like admin, operator etc) to understand which UI should be rendered(Admin/operator/client). In JWT Auth I see this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4MJe.png)
Can I store my role for an each User in my DB table with pw and login or there is another option?
And how to protect routes for an each role?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this documentation https://jwt.io/introduction/, I think you should add a field in the payload of your jwt, for exemple :

```js
{
  role: "admin"
}
```

Comment: can a normal client edit their role as admin on the browser and send you a modified token?

Comment: Yes, but that's why you are supposed to verify the validity of the token when you receive it. Making a jwt in general is not hard it's not hidden or secret.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  role: "admin"
}
```

Okay I got it from doc, but it`s not a question I asked actually